# PANDAS - Drop column based on value of cell in that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV with and I'm interested in dropping all the columns in the CSV where the value of a cell in each column equals 0. So I want to delete any column that has a 0 in the "Total Conservation (Gapped)" row. Any advice on how to achieve this?

```
Out[7]: 
                            Unnamed: 0    0        1  ... 1585 1586 1587
0                      HCoV_HKU1_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
1                 Rat_CoV_Parker_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
2                  Mouse_CoV_MHV_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
3                  Rat_CoV_HKU24_spike    x        -  ...    x    x    x
4                            EquineCoV    -        -  ...    x    x    x
5                     Rabbit_CoV_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
6                      HCoV_OC43_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
7                            CanineCoV    -        -  ...    x    x    x
8                     Bovine_CoV_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
9                  Hedgehog_CoV3_spike    x        x  ...    x    x    x
10                 Hedgehog_CoV2_spike    x        x  ...    x    x    x
11                 Hedgehog_CoV1_spike    x        x  ...    x    x    x
12                     HCoV_MERS_spike    x        x  ...    x    x    x
13        Tylonycteris_pachypus_BatCoV    x        x  ...    x    x    x
14             BCoV_Tylonycteris_spike    x        x  ...    x    x    x
15                   BCoV_SC2013_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
16                    BCoV_HKU25_spike    x        x  ...    x    x    x
17             BCoV_Pipistrellus_spike    x        x  ...    x    x    x
18                   BCoV_GD2013_spike    x        x  ...    x    x    x
19                BCoV_SARS_HKU3_spike    x        -  ...    x    x    x
20                  BCoV_HeB2013_spike    x        -  ...    x    x    x
21                   BCoV_YN2013_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
22                  BCoV_HuB2013_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
23          BCoV_SARS_like_WIV16_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
24                     HCoV_SARS_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
25           Civet_CoV_SARS_2004_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
26                     BCoV_BM48_spike    x        -  ...    x    x    x
27                  Pangolin_CoV_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
28                    HCoV_SARS2_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
29                   BCoV_RatG13_spike    -        -  ...    x    x    x
30                                 NaN  NaN      NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN
31   SARS-Clade Conservation (gap inc)    0        0  ...    0    0    0
32   MERS-Clade Conservation (gap inc)    0        0  ...    0    0    0
33   OC43-Clade Conservation (gap inc)    0        0  ...    0    0    0
34                                 NaN  NaN      NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN
35  SARS-Clade Conservation (ungapped)    0  #DIV/0!  ...    0    0    0
36  SARS-Clade Conservation (ungapped)    0        0  ...    0    0    0
37  SARS-Clade Conservation (ungapped)    0  #DIV/0!  ...    0    0    0
38                                 NaN  NaN      NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN
39         Total Conservation (Gapped)    0        0  ...    0    0    0
40       Total Conservation (Ungapped)    0        0  ...    0    0    0

[41 rows x 1589 columns]
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your question and add your desired output. However, it kinda seems, that you're using the dataframe on the wrong direction? Usually, you have many rows and a few columns and not viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, your dataframe is messy, look into how to "tidy-up" your dataframe (convert the entire first row into the columns and then you could just select on the total conservation column_ but for your messy dataframe try using .loc:

```
df2 = df.loc[(df['first column'] == 'Total Conservation (Gapped)') & (df['other interested rows'] != 0)]
```